# What will the payments be? What total interest will the student pay?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A student receives a federally backed student loan of $6,000 at 3.5% interest compounded monthly. After finishing college in 2 years, the student must amortize the loan in the next 4 years by making equal payments.

A) What will the payments be?

B) What total interest will the student pay?

*-**Progress**-*

6000= PMT (1-(1.0025)^-48)/(1.0025)= 134.14$
Is this right?

on the test they did A= P(1+i)^n first

Why?

Comment: Is this your homework? And do you have any thoughts about it?

Comment: No it's a past exam

Comment: Does the student pay back each month, or each year?

Comment: I don't know it says compounded monthly?

Comment: That just means that the interest is calculated each month, and so it matters if the student pays his loans back each month or annually, as the interest is presumably still added each month while the student is paying his debt back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let see, we have a $6000$ loan at $1.035$ interest each month.
So after $2$ years we have a $y = 6000\cdot 1.035^{24}$ debt.

Now we have 4 years, or $48$ months, to pay back, where we pay each month an $x$ amount of cash.
Now it depends on whether we pay first, then the interest is calculated, or first the interest is calculated, and then we pay, but I suppose the first.

Now, this yields the following debts:
$$\begin{matrix} \textrm{Month} & \textrm{debt} \\ 1 & (x-y)\cdot 1.035 \\ 2 & ((x-y)\cdot1.035 - x)\cdot1.035 \\ 3 & y \cdot 1.035^3 - x \cdot (1.035^3 +1.035^2+1.035) \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 48 & y\cdot 1.035^{48} - x \sum_{j=1}^{48} 1.035^j\end{matrix}$$
So now you have to solve $6000\cdot 1.035^{72} = x \sum_{j=1}^{48} 1.035^j$.

And once you know $x$, you also know the total interest.